# Breaking up text in a column

Tags: tables, paragraphs, plain-tex, columns

When the contents of a column are too long to fit on a single line, how can I have TeX break up the contents across multiple lines if the column has a variable width (such as column 2 in the example below)?

```
\offinterlineskip\tabskip=0pt
\halign to.5\hsize{
   \vrule#\strut&
   \hfil\enskip#\enskip&
   \vrule#&
   \enskip#\enskip\hfil\tabskip0pt plus1fil&
   \vrule#\tabskip0pt
\cr\noalign{\hrule}
   &\omit\hfil\enskip\bf ID\enskip\hfil&
   &\omit\span\omit\hfil\enskip\bf Description\enskip\hfil\vrule
\cr\noalign{\hrule}
   &1&
   &A description that should be broken up across several lines&
\cr\noalign{\hrule}
   &1~000&
   &A description that fits a single line&
\cr\noalign{\hrule}
   &1~000~000&
   &Another short description&
\cr\noalign{\hrule}}
\end
```

[image]

Comment: you need to put the text into a vbox of a width to be determined (or really just use latex which has convenient macros for all these things) eg tabularx X columns in this case

Comment: You can't: TeX must know a line length in order to break a paragraph into lines. An `\halign` cell is just an `\hbox`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The question actually is if (and how) the width of such a vbox can be determined.  And if LaTeX can do it, then it can be done in plain TeX, too, right?

Comment: @AngelTsankov of course you can `\input latex.ltx` into plain, but why?

Comment: You could typeset the table twice; after the first pass, get the last row with `\lastbox`, access the width of the first column and reset the table with the second column of fixed width computed from `.5\hsize` minus that width (and the intercolumn widths). Or use LaTeX and `tabularx`.

Comment: @egreg Can I only access the width of the first column through `\lastbox`?  Why not access the width of the second column instead, and save the computations?

Comment: @AngelTsankov You can access the width of *any* column: with `\lastbox` you get the last line packaged in an `\hbox` that you can `\unhbox` and then you can go backwards in it to get the columns' widths.

Comment: @egreg Can you suggest a complete answer based on this idea?  I guess you also have to "remove" the table after getting the width of whichever column you choose and before proceeding to the second pass.

Comment: the idea @egreg is sketching out is basically what happens if you use an `X` column in latex as I suggest above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typeset the table in a `\vbox`, access the last line and dismantle it to get the width of the first column. Then set the size of the second column in an appropriate way.

```
\def\myhalign#1{%
  \setbox0=\vbox{
    \tabskip=0pt
    \halign{&##\cr#1}
    \setbox0=\lastbox
    \setbox0=\hbox{\unhbox0
      \unskip % tabskip glue
      \setbox0=\lastbox % third rule
      \unskip % tabskip glue
      \setbox0=\lastbox % second column
      \unskip % tabskip glue
      \setbox0=\lastbox % second rule
      \unskip % tabskip glue
      \setbox0=\lastbox % first column
      \global\dimen1=\wd0
    }%
  }%
  \dimen0=.5\hsize
  \advance\dimen0 by -1.2pt % the rules
  \advance\dimen0 by -2em % the padding
  \advance\dimen0 by -\dimen1 % the first column
  \vbox{
    \offinterlineskip\tabskip=0pt
    \everycr{\noalign{\hrule}}
    \halign{%
      \vrule##\strut&
      \hfil\enskip##\enskip&
      \vrule##&
      \enskip\vtop{
        \normalbaselines
        \hsize=\dimen0
        \parindent=0pt
        \strut##\strut
      }\enskip\hfil&
      \vrule##\cr
      #1\crcr
    }%
  }%
}

\noindent\vrule height 0.4pt width .5\hsize

\medskip

\myhalign{
   &\omit\hfil\enskip\bf ID\enskip\hfil&
   &\omit\span\omit\hfil\enskip\bf Description\enskip\hfil\vrule
\cr
   &1&
   &A description that should be broken up across several lines&
\cr
   &1~000&
   &A description that fits a single line&
\cr
   &1~000~000&
   &Another short description&
\cr
}


\bye
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

[image]

```
\offinterlineskip\tabskip=0pt
\setbox0\hbox{\enskip1~000~000\enskip}
\newdimen\foo
\foo=.5\hsize
\advance\foo-\wd0
\advance\foo-1.2pt% 3 rules
\halign to.5\hsize{
   \vrule#\strut&
   \hfil\enskip#\enskip&
   \vrule#&
   \vtop\bgroup\hsize\foo\normalbaselines
\parindent0pt
\leftskip.5em\rightskip.5em plus 3cm#\ifhmode\unskip\strut\fi\egroup&
   \vrule#
\cr\noalign{\hrule}
   &\omit\hfil\enskip\bf ID\enskip\hfil&
   &\omit\span\omit\hfil\enskip\bf Description\enskip\hfil\vrule
\cr\noalign{\hrule}
   &1&
   &A description that should be broken up across several lines&
\cr\noalign{\hrule}
   &1~000&
   &A description that fits a single line&
\cr\noalign{\hrule}
   &1~000~000&
   &Another short description&
\cr\noalign{\hrule}}
\end
```